# Reading excel file with ActiveX

Tags: excel, vbscript, activex

I am using the following VB Script to read the contents from an Excel file.

```
        var ControlCn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");           
        var Conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = E:\\DownloadAttachment.xlsx;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        ControlCn.Open(Conn);
        var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
        var SQL = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
        rs.Open(SQL, ControlCn);
        if(rs.bof)
        {
            document.write('No Data Avaliable');
        } 
        if(!rs.bof)
        {
            rs.MoveFirst();
            var rows = "";
            while(!rs.eof)
            {
                var line = "";
                for(var i=0; i!= rs.fields.count; ++i)  
                {  
                        line += "<td>" + rs.fields(i).value + "</td>";

                }
                rows += "<tr>" + line + "</tr>";
                rs.MoveNext()
            }
            $(rows).appendTo("#itemList tbody");
        }
        rs.Close();
        ControlCn.Close(); 
    }
```

This script works when I keep the excel file opened, but when I close the excel file  the script fails to open a connection.

Comment: Maybe the connection string is wrong. Tried changing Persist Security Info=False to True? or something similar?

Comment: Yes. The problem was with the connection string only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer in case someone is stuck like me on this silly mistake.
The problem is with the connection string.

```
var Conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = E:\\DownloadAttachment.xlsx;Persist Security Info=True;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;\"";
```

is the correct connection string. For .xlsx we use Excel 12.0 instead of Excel 8.0 and the provider should be Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 instead of Jet.